# How to embed RTSP video on a HTML website?

Tags: html, video, streaming, embed, rtsp

I've tried all the ways I found stackoverflow and it does not work.
I have the link rtsp://user:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554 and I would like to embed the video on the website. How to do it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. But what you are asking is not clear i.e. what you have tried so far? share your research. Share the code which you have tried. This will help others to understand and help you.

Comment: I tried to embed VLC  <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" width="1280" height="720" id="vlc">
      <param name="target" value="rtsp://<my ip>" />
      <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" />
      <param name="controls" value="false" />
      <param name="loop" value="true" />
    </object>

Comment: "http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" returns 404

Comment: I downloaded http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win64/vlc-3.0.6-win64.msi and it also does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers do not support RTSP. you must convert to a format that browsers support like HLS or DASH.

Comment: And maybe change the format sent from the camera?
What would be the best?